# Changing the color of a widget in a nested contents of Drawer on selection in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, nested

the content of navigation drawer is populated using nested listview as follows

```
ListView.builder(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: someValue,itemBuilder: (context,indexRole){
    return  Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(' Header ${[indexRole]}'),
        ListView.builder(
          //inner contentt
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
            return ListTile(
              leading: Icon(xyz['icon'],
                color: page == index? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                    :Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.color,
              ),
              title: Text('${xyz['name']}'),
              onTap: (){

                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            );
          },itemCount: someValue,
        )
      ],
    );
  })
```

The navigation works fine, but referring to specific ListTile to be colored is the issue. thank you

[image: side drawer, widgets with same index are colored]

Answer (score 0):

did come up with the answer using the index of both the **Outer and the inner`ListView.Builder`** as follows

`color:  pageListIndex ==page && indexRole == headPtr && index == innerPtr ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor : Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.color,`

the variables are asssigned within **onTap(){}** method

```
 onTap: (){
       int indexiRole = indexRole;
       innerPtr=index;
       headPtr = indexRole;`//...`
```